# How to optionally use `window` variable in Node/Browser module?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, umd

Running a script via NodeJS which imports from a library is failing because the library references the `window` variable. Even though in the library, it looks like this:

```
{
  baseUrl: (typeof window !== undefined ? window.location.origin : '') + "/blah",
}
```

This line still results in the following error when running the script via NodeJS:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

I thought it was enough to add the `typeof window !== undefined` check but clearly that is not the case. What am I missing here? (FWIW the imported module is a UMD module.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof` gives you a string so you need to be comparing to `"undefined"`, not `undefined`.  Change your code to this:

```
{
  baseUrl: (typeof window !== "undefined" ? window.location.origin : '') + "/blah",
}
```

Comment: :face_palm: DUH! Thanks.